# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://localhost:2375

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed docker client on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) on Windows 10.0.17763 Home.

When I run

```
sudo docker ps
```

I got:

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://localhost:2375. Is the
>   docker daemon running?

and after removing docker environment variables (`unset DOCKER_HOST` , `unset DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY` , `unset DOCKER_TLS_PATH`), I still have the same issue with docker daemon:

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is
>   the docker daemon running?

When I try to start docker daemon `sudo systemctl start docker`  I am getting:

> Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory

docker version is 19.03.4

docker compose version is 1.24.1

Also restarting LxssManager win service will not help. 
What should I do?

Comment: you should not need to use with sudo I think.

Answer (score 2):

WSL is no real Linux Kernel which is why nothing, also running the Windows Subsystem for Linux as administrator by right clicking from start menu and running `sudo service docker start` does not work.

There is a new version, WSL 2 which is supposed to solve the docker issue but I did not try it our so far: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl-tech-preview/